# PageSize in kendo grid - make it clickable to show number of items displayed

Tags: javascript, html, angular, kendo-ui

I have a kendo grid component in angular 2 application, which loads the data in grid dynamically. In the grid i have a kendogridbinding where pageSize is set to 10. so suppose if i have 100 items it shows 1- 10 of 100, i am looking for making 100 as clickable so when i hover mouse over 100, hand symbol comes up and on click it will show me all 100 items.

grid.comp.html

```
<kendo-grid #grid [kendoGridBinding]="gridData" [pageSize]="10" [pageable]="true" style="cursor:pointer">
            <kendo-grid-column *ngFor="let column of columns" [field]="getColumnField(column)" [title]="getColumnTitle(column)" [width]="getColumnWidth(column)">
                <template kendoGridHeaderTemplate let-column="column">
                    <span style=color:red; [title]="column.title" (click)="onTemplateSpanClick($event)">{{column.title}} </span>
                </template>
                <template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
                    <span *ngIf="column!== 'Status'" [title]="column.title">         
                         <span [title]="column.title">
                   {{dataItem[column]}}
                   <!-- <span [innerHTML]="dataItem[column]"></span>  -->
                   </span>
                    </span>
                </template>
            </kendo-grid-column>
        </kendo-grid>
```

[![image of pagesize, 5 should be clickable 
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orMHo.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orMHo.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PagerTemplate](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/PagerTemplateDirective/) and provide the desired content (and respective event handlers and CSS for the custom elements), e.g.:

```
<ng-template 
        kendoPagerTemplate 
        let-totalPages="totalPages" 
        let-currentPage="currentPage"
        let-skip="skip"
        let-total="total">
         <kendo-pager-prev-buttons></kendo-pager-prev-buttons>
         <kendo-pager-numeric-buttons [buttonCount]="10"></kendo-pager-numeric-buttons>
         <kendo-pager-next-buttons></kendo-pager-next-buttons>
         <span>{{ skip + 1 }} - {{ skip + pageSize }} of <span class="custom" (click)="showAll()">{{ total }} items</span></span>
      </ng-template>
```

[EXAMPLE](http://plnkr.co/edit/Fdo5XerspIb13gra1h8E?p=preview)

Comment: how can i later kendopager in my html as i dont have one. any idea.